# rails 4 has_many working differently for different instances of the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations

I have the following model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friends
end


class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

The models are more complex than that, but that's the idea. Then in my rails console:

```
person = Person.new
person.friends
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

This seems right - The person has no friends yet since it's a new model, so it returns an empty array.

However, when I look up a person that has many friends and try to destroy them, I get this:

```
person = Person.where(name: 'Test')
if person
  person.friends.destroy_all
end

NoMethodError: undefined method `friends' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Person:0x007f9cf42741e0>
```

Why is the method `friends` undefined for one `person`, but not for another? I am using rails 4.0.0 and ruby 2.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Person.where` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, you are treating it as a `Person` object.

Try:

```
people = Person.where(name: 'Test')
people.each { |p| p.friends.destroy_all }
```

Example, for first person object:

```
person = Person.where(name: 'Test').first
if person
  person.friends.destroy_all
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not working differently. this is confusion because of object name you are using.

Case 1.

```
    person = Person.new
    person.friends
```

this is creating a single object so it is working fine.

Now case 2:

```
   persons= Person.where(name : 'test')   
   persons.each do |person|
     person.friends..destroy_all
   end
```

In case 2 you are getting multiple record.